# How to properly format date for django via datepicker

Tags: html, django

I am trying to populate a `DateTimeField` on a django model. I am doing it via the frontend using this extension (https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). The problem is when i submit the form, I get this error in the console `"Datetime has wrong format. Use one of these formats instead: YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm[:ss[.uuuuuu]][+HH:MM|-HH:MM|Z].` Where could the problem lie?

Model

```
class Video(models.Model):

    beginDate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Date picker

```
<input
    type="text" 
    id="from-datepicker"
    onChange={handleDate}
    data-provide="datepicker"
    name="beginDate"
    data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd"
    placeholder="Select date"
    className="form-control lesson__startDate"
    required
 />
```

Comment: Can you please show us your views and your whole HTML form? But it seems like you're only trying to submit date when somewhere in your view is expecting date and time.

Comment: try use `format='yyyy-mm-dd'`